# adding color, depending on item value in list view

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

I have a list view like this:

[image: First part]

[image: Second part]

It shows item description and how much quantity delivered.

- If all quantity delivered then, I need to show line in green.
- If any quantity delivered(partial) then, I need to show in orange.
- If no quantity delivered then, I need to show yellow.

I have given code like this,and it is not working.

```
ListView1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 8.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold)
ListView1.Items.Clear()
If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
    Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)
    Dim str(ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count) As String
    Dim lvi As ListViewItem
    Dim rr As DataRow
    Dim highlight As String = ""
    Dim temp1 As String = ""
    Dim temp2 As String = ""
    Dim temp1Sum, temp2Sum As Integer
    Dim diffCount As Integer = 0
    Dim newColumn As Integer = 0
    Dim strTemp As String
    For Each rr In dt.Rows
        For col As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
            str(col) = rr(col).ToString()
            If col > 4 And col > newColumn Then
                Dim qtyVal As String
                qtyVal = rr(col).ToString
                strTemp = qtyVal

                If temp1 = "" Then
                    temp1 = IIf(qtyVal = "", "0.00", qtyVal)
                Else
                    temp2 = temp1
                    temp1 = IIf(qtyVal = "", "0.00", qtyVal)
                    newColumn = col + 1
                End If
                If temp1 <> "" And temp2 <> "" Then
                    If temp1 <> temp2 Then
                        diffCount = diffCount + 1
                    End If

                    temp1 = ""
                    temp2 = ""
                End If
            End If

        Next
    lvi = New ListViewItem(str)
    ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
    If diffCount = 0 Then
        lvi.BackColor = Color.Green

        noofdeliver = noofdeliver + 1
        txtdelivercount.Text = noofdeliver
    ElseIf diffCount > 0 Then
        If temp2Sum = 0 Then
            lvi.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        Else
            lvi.BackColor = Color.Orange

        End If
    End If
    temp2Sum = 0
        diffCount = 0
        newColumn = 0
    Next
End If
```

Comment: any update? any one can do any help

Answer (score 0):

Put this line `ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)` after the color changing

**TEST CODE**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim lvi = New ListViewItem("foo " & ListView1.Items.Count + 1)
    lvi.BackColor = Color.Red
    ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)

End Sub
```

Comment: what is the use of that?

Comment: When you do `ListView1.Items.Add()` the reference to the real object is lost. I added a test code

Answer (score 0):

here the actual problem is...
you are using `str` variable as array but you are assigning to `ListViewItem` as `lvi = New ListViewItem(str)` without specifying the index for `str` array. As you specified in code it always takes the first value of the array only..

solution: when you are assigning array `str` value to `ListViewItemlvi` specify the corresponding index value.